# Cannot assign result of Parse PFQuery to instance variable of my controller Class in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to assign the value returned from the result of a Parse query to an instance variable of my view controller class called "currentProfile". Although the function retrieves the data from the server okay, it seems like it doesn't assign it to my instance variable.

This is my code :

```
let query = PFUser.query()
    query!.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(self.profileId) {
        (profile: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && profile != nil {
            print(profile)
            self.currentProfile = (profile as? PFUser)!
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    print(currentProfile)
```

So when I print profile the first time it prints it correctly, however when I print currentProfile outside the function it actually doesn't print anything.

If you have any idea why this is happening or know how could I fix it, it would be greatly appreciated if you could let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see it printing `currentProfile` **before** it prints `profile`?

Comment: It's asynchronous, I guess you're testing it before it's completed?